# Why Did 'Lucifer' Season 3 End the Way It Did?

Tags: plot-explanation, lucifer

So I recently finished watching the current three seasons of *Lucifer* on Netflix, and in "A Devil of My Word" (the third to last episode of Season 3) (spoiler alert below)...

Chloe sees Lucifer's devil face and realizes he's been telling the truth about being the devil.

However, the following episode ("Boo Normal") is just a one-off episode about Ella, with no direct/significant mention of Chloe seeing Lucifer's devil face. And of course, the last episode of the season is essentially a giant reset button.

But even if the writers/producers/whoever else decided to hit the reset button in the last episode of the season, I'm a little bit confused/curious about **why they decided to go with the storyline they did in "Boo Normal" and entirely avoid dealing with the fallout/aftermath from the previous episode (of Chloe realizing the truth about Lucifer). Might anybody know the reason for that?**

Comment: I'll have to check, but I think Boo Normal was suppose to be apart of season 4, but upon FOX's cancellation, they tacked it onto the ending. I think it aired 2 weeks after the season 3 finale. -- But Netflix has saved Lucifer, so it will be interesting to see how it fits into the season 4 narrative.

Comment: oh em gee, Detective! *Two* episodes I didn't know existed! [Boo Normal & Once Upon a Time] Now I know what I'm watching tomorrow night ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin bad idea. They don't at all fit into anything. You wouldn't miss out on them if you didn't watch them

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Some people love alternate realities and/or "what if scenarios" where dynamics get switched around in order to see what sticks and what doesn't. A lot of people thought they were a lot of fun, but again, it's unclear why they would of been/could still be apart of season 4 and that in itself might intrigue some viewers, as they wait for Netflix to drop the first five episodes :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essentially, *Boo Normal* and the subsequent episode *Once Upon a Time* were intended to be part of Season 4 as (possibly) stand-alone episodes.

However, as the show was cancelled the network decided to air the episodes as "bonus" episodes as they were essentially not part of any existing continuity (pending the arrival of the recently announced Season 4).

Kevin Alejando (who directed the latter) said...

> “It’s a ‘what-if?’ world,” Alejandro said of “Once Upon a Time.” “It’s a universe that doesn’t exist. So we got to joke around and call it a ‘re-pilot’ episode, because all of the traditional ‘Lucifer’ roles didn’t really necessarily have to completely apply in this episode.”
>
> <sup>[**Source**](https://www.thewrap.com/lucifer-kevin-alejandro-savelucifer-tom-ellis-bonus-episodes-once-upon-a-time/)</sup>

---

> “It’s a world in which God questions — played by Neil Gaiman, by the way — would Chloe (Lauren German) and Lucifer’s paths still have crossed, had he not put Chloe in Lucifer’s path?” the actor added. “So this whole episode entertains that idea in a very beautiful way. It was super cool to recreate this ‘Lucifer’ universe with subtle differences. And still the challenge was to maintain the characters, and much of the universe the audience already knows and loves

Comment: Please Note: Netflix saved Lucifer and season 4 is coming sometime this year (but split into two parts) and some speculate these episodes gave clues, such as introducing new characters. So it actually remains to be seen if those episode will factor back into the season 4 narrative as originally attended. https://www.cnet.com/news/netflix-saves-lucifer-dc-comics-tv-series/